# change default form email type regex in symfony2

Tags: regex, forms, email, symfony, types

Using Symfony 2.3.4.
When I create a form with a field in it that's supposed to process emails I go and use the default email type:

```
builder->add('email', 'email', array(
                'label' => 'Email',))
```

with only this, it successfully validates user inputs, only not the way I want, meaning:

how it works:

```
me --> notallowed       
me@gmail --> allowed
```

how I need it to work:

```
me --> notallowed
me@gmail --> notallowed
me@gmail.com --> allowed
```

summing up:

I figured what I need is to change/customize the default regex that validates this which I guess is deep in one of the many files in symfony.

appreciate any tips regarding this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the validation that you are seeing here is the browser based HTML5 validation.  The message that pops up if `me` is entered comes right from your browser, no Symfony involved.  I find HTML5 validation unreliable for the most part.  Best practice is to validate on the server side, and use some type of javascript validation for the client side.

for more info on setting up server side validation, see [the symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html), they give some great examples and it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle email validation by javascript . Call  any method on form submit like

```
function validate(){
  var email=$('#email').val();
  if(email!=""){
   var re =/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if (!re.test(email)) {
        alert('please Enter Valid email address');  

        }
    }

<form onSubmit="return validate();">
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Please Enter your Email address" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this following link for form field type email 
[Symfony form type email](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/email.html)

If you want jquery validation for email

```
$('#formId').validate({
errorClass: 'help-block',
rules: {
    'textFieldName': {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }
},
messages: {
    'textFieldName': {
        email: "Invalid Email Address"
    }
},

highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).parent().parent().removeClass("success").addClass("error");
},

unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).parent().parent().removeClass("error").addClass("success");
}
```

}); // validate